# update record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add new image to my "Place" model. is it good practice to add new method/action to the controller and add new form to from Place show page?

if no then what is the best practice?

in the controller

```
def add_images
@place = Place.find(params[:id])

#DO THE CHANGES HERE

@palce.save;
redirect_to places_path
end
```

in the route

```
match 'places/:id/add_images' => 'places#add_images'
```

in the view

```
<%= form_tag @place.id.to_s+'/add_images', :method => 'post', :multipart => true do %>
 <!-- just test -->
 <div class="actions">
 <%= submit_tag "submit new images" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I updated the question with my solution I dont know if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use new form: form_for @place with image file_field, 
use update action in controller

```
def update
  @place.update_attributes params[:place]
end
```

Comment: this will update the already inserted image. what if I want to add new image to the Model.

Comment: It isn't necessary to add new action. You may add/update image in place update form. It doesn't matter in respect to good practice, it will be new form or you use standard(bootstrap) form for edit place. But, I think good practice, if you didn't add new action, use update.
Only one point when new action may be useful - you should redirect to another path.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you want to modify your model in some way, the good practice for these cases is to add a migration, read the [rails guide about migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for more information.

Once you have run the migration and your DB is updated you can edit the controllers/views as you want.